# Invalid Number of arguments in Solidity

Tags: javascript, html, ethereum, solidity

First of all, I'm a rookie, so please bear with me. I have created a contract that includes an HTML frontend and a Javascript file. The contract compiles properly, but when I try to post an item (calls the sellArticle function), I get the error "Invalid Number of arguments in Solidity" I can't seem to find the solution to this one, so I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.
I have posted the code below.

INDEX.HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Rent My Place</title>
<!-- Title will appear as a tab in browser on webpage -->
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- Application -->
  <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- stylesheet refers to the look of the page, Font, color-->

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
<!-- container that contains title panel-->
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<p style="font-size:80px;padding: 1em;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px; border:10px;border-style:solid;border-color:#c3c3c3;">
  <font color = "#880015" >Rent My Place</font></p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12" id="article-list">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <p id="account" class="welcome pull-right"></p>
  <p id="accountBalance" class="welcome pull-left"></p>
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
  <div class="panel-title">
<p style="font-size:24px;padding: 1em;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px; border:5px;border-style:solid;border-color:#c3c3c3;">
  <font color = "#880015">Renter's Tip: </font><font color = "#000000">Inspect the property before you send money.</font><br><font color = "#880015">Landlord's Tip: </font><font color = "#000000">Meet prospective tenants in person.</font></p>
<!-- Button that opens second window to a form to fill out-->
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sellArticle">Post a Rental</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- when the event button gets click, it will show the list-->
<ul id="events" class="collapse list-group"></ul>
  </div>

  <div id="articlesRow" class="row">
<!-- ARTICLES with pertinent item information LOAD HERE -->
  </div>
</div>
  </div>

<!--Result that is displayed after input-->
  <div id="articleTemplate" style="display: none;">
<div class="row-lg-12">
  <div class="panel panel-default panel-article">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
  <strong>Beds</strong>: <span class="beds"></span><br/>
  <strong>Baths</strong>: <span class="baths"></span><br/>
  <strong>Address</strong>: <span class="propaddress"></span><br/>
  <strong>Rental Price</strong>: <span class="rental_price"></span><br/>
  <strong>Property Type</strong>: <span class="property_type"></span><br/>
  <strong>Description</strong>: <span class="description"></span><br/>
  <strong>Property is available for showing</strong>: <span class="available"></span><br/>
  <strong>Contact Email</strong>: <span class="contact_email"></span><br/>
  <!--<strong>Sold by</strong>: <span class="article-seller"></span><br/>-->
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
  <button type="button" class= "btn btn-primary btn-success btn-buy" onclick="App.buyArticle(); return false;">Buy</button>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

  <!-- Modal form to sell an article -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="sellArticle" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Rent Your Place</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

  <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <form>
<div class="form-group">
  <!--NOTE: For radio buttons to work, 'name' field must match-->
  <label for="property_type">Property Type</label>
  <input type="radio" name="property" id="house" value="house" > House
  <input type="radio" name="property" id="apartment" value="apartment" > Apartment
  <input type="radio" name="property" id="duplex" value="duplex" > Duplex
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="propaddress">Address</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="propaddress" placeholder="Enter the address">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="beds">Beds</label>
  <input type="radio" name="beds" id="studio" value="0"> Studio
  <input type="radio" name="beds" id="one" value="1"> One
  <input type="radio" name="beds" id="two" value="2"> Two
  <input type="radio" name="beds" id="three" value="3"> Three +
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="baths">Baths</label>
  <input type="radio" name="baths" id="one" value="1"> One
  <input type="radio" name="baths" id="two" value="2"> Two
  <input type="radio" name="baths" id="three" value="3"> Three +
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="rental_price">Rent (in USD)</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rental_price" placeholder="$" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="description">Description</label>
  <textarea type="text" class="form-control vresize" id="description" placeholder="Describe your property" maxlength="255"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="available"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="available" value="available" id="available"> Property is available for showing
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="contact_email">Contact Email</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_email" placeholder="Enter your contact email">
</div>
  </form>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="App.sellArticle(); return false;">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
  </div>

</div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer" class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="navbar-inner navbar-content-center text-center">
<p class="text-muted" credit><a href="http://www.axbean.com">AXbean</a> - &copy; 2018</a></p>
  </div>
</nav>
  </div>


  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/RentalApp.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/truffle-contract.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

RENTALAPP.JS:

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},
  account: 0x0,
  loading: false,

  init: function() {
return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function() {
// initialize web3
if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  //reuse the provider of the Web3 object injected by Metamask
  App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
} else {
  //create a new provider and plug it directly into our local node
  App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
}
web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

App.displayAccountInfo();

return App.initContract();
  },

  displayAccountInfo: function() {
web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
  if(err === null) {
App.account = account;
$('#account').text(account);
web3.eth.getBalance(account, function(err, balance) {
  if(err === null) {
$('#accountBalance').text(web3.fromWei(balance, "ether") + " ETH");
  }
})
  }
});
  },

  initContract: function() {
$.getJSON('RentalContract.json', function(chainListArtifact) {
  //added May24 to json file name
  // get the contract artifact file and use it to instantiate a truffle contract abstraction
  App.contracts.RentalContract = TruffleContract(chainListArtifact);
  // set the provider for our contracts
  App.contracts.RentalContract.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
  // listen to events
  App.listenToEvents();
  // retrieve the article from the contract
  return App.reloadArticles();
});
  },

  reloadArticles: function() {
//avoid reentry bugs
if(App.loading){
  return;
}
App.loading = true;

// refresh account information because the balance might have changed
App.displayAccountInfo();

var chainListInstance;

App.contracts.RentalContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  chainListInstance = instance;
  return chainListInstance.getArticlesForSale();
}).then(function(articlesIds) {

  // retrieve the article placeholder and clear it
  $('#articlesRow').empty();

  for(var i = 0; i < articlesIds.length; i++){
var articleId = articlesIds[i];
chainListInstance.articles(articleId.toNumber()).then(function(article){
  App.displayArticle(article[0], article[1], article[3], article[4], article[5]);
});
  }
  App.loading = false;

}).catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err.message);
  App.loading = false;
});
  },

  displayArticle: function(id, seller, beds, baths, propaddress, rental_price, property_type, description, available, contact_email) {
var articlesRow = $('#articlesRow');

//var etherPrice = web3.fromWei(price, "ether");

var articleTemplate = $("#articleTemplate");
//articleTemplate.find('.panel-title').text(propaddress);
articleTemplate.find('.beds').text(beds);
articleTemplate.find('.baths').text(baths);
articleTemplate.find('.propaddress').text(propaddress);
articleTemplate.find('.rental_price').text(rental_price);
articleTemplate.find('.property_type').text(property_type);
articleTemplate.find('.description').text(description);
articleTemplate.find('.available').text(available);
articleTemplate.find('.contact_email').text(contact_email);
  //  articleTemplate.find('.article_price').text(etherPrice + " ETH");
articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').attr('data-id', id);
// articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').attr('data-value', etherPrice);

//seller
if(seller == App.account){
  articleTemplate.find('.article-seller').text("You");
  articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').hide();
}else{
  articleTemplate.find('.article-seller').text(seller);
  articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').show();
}
//add this new article
articlesRow.append(articleTemplate.html());
  },

  sellArticle: function() {
// retrieve the detail of the article
  //  var _article_name = $('#article_name').val();
var _description = $('#description').val();
var _beds = $('#beds').val();
var _baths = $('#baths').val();
var _propaddress = $('#propaddress').val();
var _rental_price = $('#rental_price').val();
var _property_type = $('#property_type').val();
var _available = $('#available').val();
var _contact_email = $('#contact_email').val();
  //  var _article_price = $('#article_price').val();
  //  var _price = web3.toWei(parseFloat($('#article_price').val() || 0), "ether");

if((_description.trim() == '') || (rental_price == 0)) {
  // nothing to sell
  return false;
}

App.contracts.RentalContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  return instance.sellArticle(_description, _beds, _baths, _propaddress, _rental_price, _property_type, _available, _contact_email, {
from: App.account,
gas: 500000
  });
}).then(function(result) {

}).catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
  },

  // listen to events triggered by the contract
  listenToEvents: function() {
App.contracts.RentalContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  instance.LogSellArticle({}, {}).watch(function(error, event) {
if (!error) {
  $("#events").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + event.args._propaddress + ' is now for sale</li>');
} else {
  console.error(error);
}
App.reloadArticles();
  });

  instance.LogBuyArticle({}, {}).watch(function(error, event) {
if (!error) {
  $("#events").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + event.args._buyer + ' bought ' + event.args._propaddress + '</li>');
} else {
  console.error(error);
}
App.reloadArticles();
  });
});
  },

  buyArticle: function() {
event.preventDefault();

// retrieve the article price and data
var _articleId = $(event.target).data('id');
var _price = parseFloat($(event.target).data('value'));

App.contracts.RentalContract.deployed().then(function(instance){
  return instance.buyArticle(_articleId, {
from: App.account,
value: web3.toWei(_price, "ether"),
gas: 500000
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
  }
};

$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
App.init();
  });
});
```

CONTRACT:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;


 import "./Ownable.sol";


contract RentalContract is Ownable {

  struct Article{
  uint id;
  address seller;
  address buyer;
  uint beds;
  uint baths;
  string propaddress;
  uint256 rental_price;
  uint property_type;
  string description;
  bool available;
  string contact_email;
  }
  mapping(uint => Article) public articles;

  uint articleCounter;

event LogSellArticle(
uint indexed _id,
address indexed _seller,
  //  uint _beds,
  //  uint _baths,
string _propaddress,
uint256 _rental_price
  //  uint _property_type,
  //  string _description,
  //  bool _available,
  //  string _contact_email
  );
  event LogBuyArticle(
uint indexed _id,
address indexed _seller,
address indexed _buyer,
  //  uint _beds,
  //  uint _baths,
string _propaddress,
uint256 _rental_price
  //  uint _property_type,
  //  string _description,
  //  bool _available,
  //  string _contact_email

);

function kill() public onlyOwner {

selfdestruct(owner);
}

  function sellArticle(uint _beds, uint _baths, string _propaddress, uint256 _rental_price, uint _property_type, string _description, bool _available, string _contact_email) public {
articleCounter++;

articles[articleCounter] = Article(
  articleCounter,
 msg.sender,
0x0,
 _beds,
 _baths,
 _propaddress,
 _rental_price,
 _property_type,
 _description,
 _available,
 _contact_email
 );

  //  LogSellArticle(articleCounter, msg.sender, _beds, _baths, _propaddress, _rental_price, _property_type, _description, _available, _contact_email);
LogSellArticle(articleCounter, msg.sender, _propaddress, _rental_price);
  }
function getNumberOfArticles() public view returns (uint){
   return articleCounter;
   }


   function getArticlesForSale() public view returns (uint[]){

 uint[] memory articleIds = new uint[](articleCounter);
 uint numberOfArticlesForSale = 0;

 for(uint i = 1; i <= articleCounter; i++){

   if(articles[i].buyer == 0x0){

 articleIds[numberOfArticlesForSale] = articles[i].id;

 numberOfArticlesForSale++;

   }
 }

 uint[] memory forSale = new uint[](numberOfArticlesForSale);
 for(uint j = 0; j < numberOfArticlesForSale; j++){

 forSale[j] = articleIds[j];

 }
 return forSale;

   }


 function buyArticle(uint _id) payable public {

   require(articleCounter > 0);
   require(_id > 0 && _id <= articleCounter);

   Article storage article = articles[_id];

   require(article.buyer == 0x0);

   require(msg.sender != article.seller);

   require(msg.value == article.rental_price);

   article.buyer = msg.sender;

   article.seller.transfer(msg.value);
   // LogBuyArticle(_id, article.seller, article.buyer, article.beds, article.baths, article.propaddress, article.rental_price, article.property_type, article.description, article.available, article.contact_email);
LogBuyArticle(_id, article.seller, article.buyer, article.propaddress, article.rental_price);
 }
}
```

Comment: For future reference, there is also an Ethereum Stack Exchange site:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're passing in a 10th argument into being the sellArticle function, being:

```
{
  from: App.account,
  gas: 500000
}
```

but in your contract, the function sellArticle is not a payable function, so I would think it will throw an error. You can try making it payable.